# I/flutter (23123): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'BannerModel'

Tags: flutter

ماهوا الحل لوسمحتوا I/flutter (23123): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'BannerModel'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAgvW.jpg)

Comment: please provide snippet code instead of screenshoot image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it needs to be

```
banners.add(BannerModel.fromjson(element));
```